# Can I use Spotify Web API for creating Android/iOS Web app?

Tags: android, ios, spotify, spotify-app

I want to develop a web application for Android and iOS using HTML5 and Spotify Web API.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just parse you queries to your web server and return the results as JSON